# Set colors from array to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing some colors. I also have a div with some child elements. What I'm trying to accomplish is that each child element will get a color from the array. I'm close, and I can console log the colors, but at the moment the child's get assigned the last color in the array.

```js
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];
var setColors = customizeContainer.childNodes;
for (var i = 1; i < setColors.length; i += 2) {
 for (var x = 0; x < colors.length; x++) {
  setColors[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x];
 }
}
```

```html
  <div id="customizeMenu" class="col l12">
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
    <div class="col l1"></div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why the double loop?

Comment: Please describe the desired output

Comment: check my edit, uploaded an img that describe what im trying to accomplish. Each element should have a different color.

Comment: @SanderHellesø you have 8 colors but 9 elements. What color should the last have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to target elements. The following is more simple and cleaner:

```js
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];

var el = document.querySelectorAll('#customizeMenu > .l1');
//OR (If you have the older browser)
//var el =[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#customizeMenu > .l1'));
el.forEach(function(item, i){
  item.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
});
```

```html
<div id="customizeMenu" class="col l12">
  <div class="col l1">A</div>
  <div class="col l1">B</div>
  <div class="col l1">C</div>
  <div class="col l1">D</div>
  <div class="col l1">E</div>
  <div class="col l1">F</div>
  <div class="col l1">J</div>
  <div class="col l1">H</div>
  <div class="col l1">I</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.forEach()` on a NodeList is not supported by all browsers yet. Use `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.l1'))` for full support. You could also use ES6 `Array.from()` but keeping full support, the former is the way to go.

Comment: @frosty, thanks for the point. I have updated the answer to mention the point.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will loop the colors once they are all used.

```js
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];
var customizeContainer = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#customizeMenu > div'));

customizeContainer.forEach(function(node, i) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.length];
});
```

```css
#customizeMenu>div {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="customizeMenu" class="col l12">
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
</div>
```

---

The problem with your code was that you were looping over all the colors and assigning them for each node. So they all got the last color.

Another problem (*that you mentioned in the comments*) about the nodes being every 2 is because the `childNodes` returns text nodes and comments as well. So you either need to use `children` or use `document.querySelectorAll` to select the wanted elements directly.

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 bugs:

1. Miss the height of child div(So you will not see the div display& changed.)
2. Loop error(You should use one loop.)

```js
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];
var customizeContainer = document.getElementById("customizeMenu");
var setColors = customizeContainer.children;
for (var i = 0; i < setColors.length; i++) {
  setColors[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
.l1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="customizeMenu" class="col l12">
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
  <div class="col l1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working snippet.

You can avoid the double loop and make your array of elements with getElementsByClassName();

Hope it helps

```js
var setColors = document.getElementsByClassName('l1');
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];

for (var i = 0; i < setColors.length; i++) {
    setColors[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  }
```

```css
.l1 {
  min-width: 5vw;
  min-height 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="customizeMenu" class="col l12">
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
  <div class="col l1">&nbsp</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you're doing wrong in your code

- Double loop: Iterating over the child nodes and the colors array unnecessarily
- Incrementing the counter by 2 in the first loop

You need to iterate over `colors` array once and if there is corresponding child node exists for the index, set the color

```
var colors = ["#e57373", "#ba68c8", "#90caf9", "#4db6ac", "#dce775", "#ffb74d", "#b0bec5", "#81c784"];
var setColors = customizeContainer.childNodes;
for (var i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
        if (setColors[i] != 'undefined') {
            setColors[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason for having a double loop is because the child elements is getting sorted in a really weird way. the elements is actually 1-3-5 etc.. 0-2-4 is just a "text" element and idk why that is

Comment: @SanderHellesø that would be because you use `.childNodes` which returns text nodes (*whitespace between the `div` elements*) as well.

Comment: ahh, now I see. Thanks for that Gaby.